# How to use javascript in the code behind file to get the dynamically generated textbox text in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I dynamically generated Textbox in the UI according to the database value. Now on the button click event I want get the text of this textboxes in the .cs file using javascript.

Comment: What did you try?  Please provide some code.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure is this what you want. But here is sample how to get textbox value created in code behind and retrieve value from javascript

Code In Front

```
    <div>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlDynamicControl" runat="server">

        </asp:Panel>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnGetValue" runat="server" Text="Test" OnClientClick="return clickGetValue();" />
    </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function clickGetValue() {
        var control = document.getElementById('txtTest');
        // Better Ways
        var myControl = document.getElementById('<%=pnlDynamicControl.FindControl("txtTest").ClientID %>');


        // Check & Alert
        if (control != undefined) alert('Hardcode ID ways value is ' + control.value);

        // Check & Alert
        if (myControl != undefined) alert('C# findcontrol ways value is ' + myControl.value);

        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Code Behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // Add to Panel
    TextBox txtTest = new TextBox();
    txtTest.ID = "txtTest";
    this.pnlDynamicControl.Controls.Add(txtTest);

}
```